# Want a USSD Server Simulator

Tags: ussd, jsmpp

I need to simulate SMPP messages from USSD Gateway and USSD Application Server

I have a USSD Gateway application using the JSMPP Library and need a gateway to receive the USSDs sent from this library

Is there any open source USSD Server or even an application that I can rely on to complete the ussd cycle

Exactly what I need is sort of application that can listed to a port on my localhost to respond to incoming ussd messages

Answer (score 3):

Try [activeXperts free smpp simulator](http://www.activexperts.com/freeware/). It has limited functionality, but it works.

Or you can try building one using [cloudhopper-smpp](https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp) which has SmppServer & Simulator codes.

Comment: Thank you, it was several months ago that I already left the company that I worked for for this issue, sorry I can't test it anymore